# In python, do we have class encapsulation at the level of the object?

Tags: python

I was bitten by using the `is` operator when i should have been using `==`.  Am aware that the former tests for equality of the objects' identities and that the latter tests for equality of the objects' contents.

Using `is`, i thought, also implicitly tests for the equality of the contents.  For example `if a is b` is true, then the contents must be the same.  This was the working assumption and i believe that it's still true.  But what was discovered, and should have been known, is that if `if a is b` is false, then the contents of a and b may or may not be the same.

Example (Python 3.3.3):

```
class Food:
    def favourite_restaurant(self):
        return "the foo diner"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    fr = "the juice bar"
    print('%r  is  %r: %r' % (fr, 'the juice bar', (fr is 'the juice bar')))
    print('%r  ==  %r: %r' % (fr, 'the juice bar', (fr == 'the juice bar')))

    f = Food()
    result = f.favourite_restaurant()
    print('%r  is  %r: %r' % (result, 'the foo diner', (result is 'the foo diner')))
    print('%r  ==  %r: %r' % (result, 'the foo diner', (result == 'the foo diner')))
```

The first print block says:

```
'the juice bar'  is  'the juice bar': True
'the juice bar'  ==  'the juice bar': True
```

The second print block says:

```
result: 'the foo diner'
'the foo diner'  is  'the foo diner': False
'the foo diner'  ==  'the foo diner': True
```

It seems that objects instantiated within the instance of a class have their own group of ids, separate from objects outside the class.

My understanding that encapsulation in python is really a matter for 'consenting adults'.  Do we actually have encapsulation at some lower level?

Comment: Additional detail:  `A is B` == `id(A) == id(B)` (where `id` returns [an integer unique to that object for the duration that object exists](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#id))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with encapsulation, and everything with a Python implementation detail as to *when* string literals produce a string object.

What is specifically happening here is that Python uses *constants* to store literal values used in code. Your `'the juice bar'` value is such a constant.

The compiler has stored `'the juice bar'` with the code block object for the module, and is reusing that object. You are not creating *new* string values in the `__name__ == '__main__'` block.

Functions get their own code blocks, which includes their own constants, and thus their own string objects.

Demonstration:

```
>>> import dis
>>> code = compile('''\
... fr = "the juice bar"
... print('%r  is  %r: %r' % (fr, 'the juice bar', (fr is 'the juice bar')))
... print('%r  ==  %r: %r' % (fr, 'the juice bar', (fr == 'the juice bar')))
... ''', '<stdin>', 'exec')
>>> code.co_consts
('the juice bar', '%r  is  %r: %r', '%r  ==  %r: %r', None)
>>> dis.dis(code)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('the juice bar') 
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (fr) 

  2           6 LOAD_NAME                1 (print) 
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 ('%r  is  %r: %r') 
             12 LOAD_NAME                0 (fr) 
             15 LOAD_CONST               0 ('the juice bar') 
             18 LOAD_NAME                0 (fr) 
             21 LOAD_CONST               0 ('the juice bar') 
             24 COMPARE_OP               8 (is) 
             27 BUILD_TUPLE              3 
             30 BINARY_MODULO        
             31 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             34 POP_TOP              

  3          35 LOAD_NAME                1 (print) 
             38 LOAD_CONST               2 ('%r  ==  %r: %r') 
             41 LOAD_NAME                0 (fr) 
             44 LOAD_CONST               0 ('the juice bar') 
             47 LOAD_NAME                0 (fr) 
             50 LOAD_CONST               0 ('the juice bar') 
             53 COMPARE_OP               2 (==) 
             56 BUILD_TUPLE              3 
             59 BINARY_MODULO        
             60 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             63 POP_TOP              
             64 LOAD_CONST               3 (None) 
             67 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is a disassembly of the bytecode for just the `fr` test; note the `LOAD_CONST` references; these load a constant (stored at position `0` to both set `fr` and to later compare if `fr is 'the juice bar'`) is the same object.

The function object has a similar `co_const` construct, which is what Python dutifully returns when called:

```
>>> class Food:
...     def favourite_restaurant(self):
...         return "the foo diner"
... 
>>> Food.favourite_restaurant.__code__.co_consts
(None, 'the foo diner')
>>> dis.dis(Food.favourite_restaurant)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('the foo diner') 
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

As a result, the `'the foo diner'` string in the method is not the same object as the `'the foo diner'` string used in your `__name__ == '__main__'` block further down.

Armed with this knowledge you can generate wholly **new** string objects:

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> b = 'bar'
>>> ab = a + ' ' + b
>>> ab is a + ' ' + b
False
>>> ab == a + ' ' + b
True
```

Generally speaking, you are right. `is` always tests for identity, `==` for equality. If the identity test passes, then it is **usually** true that the objects are equal too.

There is one big exception in the standard library:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> nan is nan
True
>>> nan == nan
False
```

The Not-a-number floating point constant is never equal to anything. Not even with itself.

It should be noted that Python translates `op1 == op2` into a call to the [`object.__eq__()` special hook method](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__), which is free to return whatever it likes. Usually that's a boolean, but that is not required:

> By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an if statement), Python will call `bool()` on the value to determine if the result is true or false.